# Design a circuit which generate at output the sequences of 3-bit signal

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

I want to create a circuit according to table below. CLK, MOD and RST are inputs, Q1 Q2 Q3 - outputs. The signal on the output should change at the active edge of CLK.
What is the best approach to construct such a sequential logic? 
I only know how to deal with combinational logic so far. Any hint of where to start?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in this homework assignment you have not show what **you** have tried. No doubt there are examples in your textbook and/or shown in the classes you took.

Comment: I do not ask someone to solve it. I am asking to give a hint or algorithm for solving it.

Comment: how you can try to do something if you have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Hint: Karnaugh diagram. Instead of CLK, you have three counter inputs to the logic table. You may want to reduce the RST variable first.

Comment: @Janka how to apply Karnaugh diagram here if I have seven different signals at outputs corresponding each pair of inputs?

Comment: @alevdyk Hint: you can use more than one Karnaugh map.

Comment: First of all @FakeMoustache, how do you know its homework? All I see is that he has some task associated with school. Secondly, why does someone have to type up pages of work that lead nowhere?  How does that make sense?  What measure of work is necessary to prove to you that someone doesnt even know where to begin? Who is obligated on a Q&A site to produce the answer, as best they can, as they ask the question?  If youre uncomfortable answering the specific prb (perhaps you dont know how), instead of criticizing the questioner why dont you give a broader conceptual explanation of how instead.

Comment: I vote to keep this question open because despite @FakeMoustache inability or unwillingness to answer, I think its a legitimate and valuable question worthy of a response, and contributes nicely to the discussion topics that this site is based on. The point of this site is to answer questions that other people, who are skilled to the point of triviality, can competently and reliably answer. Who are you to shut down a question you arrogantly perceive to be "beneath you"?  Sorry if youre not *entertained* enough, but that isnt the purpose of this site.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum *how do you know its homework?* Ahem, the first sentence: *School task.* Also regarding your rant: this is not what this site is about. You and OP might want to read the help section where it says that you can ask questions about homework and school tasks but that you have to show **what you tried**. The fact that you **dont have a clue** is no excuse. How the **Karnaugh map** map works is explained in all books about digital logic. Explain to me why **you** need someone to write a tailor made answer here ??

Comment: ok, @FakeMoustache, how to apply a Karnaugh map here if I have one input for example 00 and sequence of 7 outputs 000, 101, 001, 111, 101, 110, 000.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum, correct, FakeMoustache does this a lot (italics, bold, snarling arrogance, rant, bore). That is not the purpose of this site. The OP has not asked for the answer, they have asked for guidance i.e. they want to learn and the solitary purpose of this site is to promote learning through helping others. Well done you for showing proper engineering.

Comment: OP, you could consider a 4-output/4-output ROM but that feels like it sidesteps the point of the question, which I imagined was to identify a pattern in the truth table. At first glance I can't, will try to get into crossword-minded mode and see if a counter with gated outputs reveals itself.

Comment: @alevdyk: Don't care about RST first. When someone has a counting sequence, separating the counter stage from the output logic map often helps. Then you have 4 inputs: C0, C1, C2 and MOD. I answered *Karnaugh diagram* because you wrote it's a school task and that's the way how your teacher most likely wants you to recap what you learned.

Comment: Homework problems should at least have an attempt to solve, although here the OP is asking for a hint. Asking for a method to solve seems fine, but what should be avoided solving the problem outright. I think the end goal would be to keep EE.SE a place to answer questions, but not a place for handouts. It doesn't help people to solve their problems for them.

Comment: @FakeMoustache You were asked an explicit question directed at you specifically for your amazing skills. On Feb 19th, 2017. Why havent you responded yet?  If youre going to quote me with italics, the least you could do is get past the first sentence before you criticize it, fool. Your arrogant retort was completely unnecessary and unfounded had you bothered to read just a sentence more than you did.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to implement a moore machine. [Here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Seq/impl.html) is some guidance on how to implement such. Below the structure of moore machines.

[image: Structure of a moore machine]

Some other thoughts:

- The next state logic will probably be a counter that counts 0 to 6.
- RST will reset the counter.
- The output logic will then - depending on the counter output and the MOD input - set the output Q according your table.
- Buffer MOD so we don't get a mealy.

I hope this could help you at least a little bit.